# How to fetch a variable in jQuery function from jsp?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I've a variable in jsp which has been passed from servlet. Now I want fetch the value of that variable in Jquery function

Here is my servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("bt", list);
request.setAttribute("rep", docbase);
request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Here is my jsp where I'm retrieving the variable:

```
<%String repository = (String)request.getAttribute("rep"); %>
```

Here is my jQuery where I want to fetch the value of "repository":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var name = $('select[name="doctype"]').attr('id');
          alert($.name);
            $.ajax({
             url:'',
             type:'post',
             cache:false,
             success: function(response){


             }
            });

        });


        </script>
```

I'm very new to jQuery, any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you can write a code something like this. But it's not a clean way of doing it. Why do you want to do it? You can do it via AJAX calls.

Here is the sample code

    <sciprt type="text/javascript">
      var myVariable = <%=request.getAttribute("rep");%>
    </script>

Comment: @user2531799 I know use of scriptlets is very much discouraged but I'm very new to JSTL and EL. Can you provide any link where I can look into?

Comment: You can do var myVariable =  '${RequestAttributeVariable}'; that is in above example I have used rep, So the actual implementation will be
var myVariable = '${rep}'; 
Remember to use single quotes and then your JSTL code or EL code